# wordpress plugin works on local host but NOT on remote server

Tags: javascript, wordpress, localhost, remote-server

I wrote a wp plugin which works fine on local host. it creates child theme directory and copies home.php there. But 'home' tab shows the old content from the parent theme. Only when I rename home.php to index.php it works. This is my home.php

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #container -->
```

Also I have script1.js file in /js folder which should adda a textbox to the  block but it doesn't. I embed the script like this:

```
define('jsdir',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js');
wp_enqueue_script('dk_js_myplugin',jsdir.'/script1.js',array('jquery'));
```

but firebug doesn't show it on the page.
Both problems doesn't exist on local installation of wordpress with xampp
Thanks for your time, any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Check your server error logs for any permission errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
define( 'jsdir', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/' . dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ )) . '/js' );
```

Expression `dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ))` return plugin location in directory `wp-content/plugins`. Read about [plugin_basename()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_basename). Constant `WP_PLUGIN_URL` return absolute path to plugins directory.

In code of your plugin try:

```
<?php

var_dump( WP_PLUGIN_URL );
var_dump( dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ )));

// output should be like this:
string(36) "http://domain.tld/wp-content/plugins" 
string(9) "my-plugin"
```

Init func for adding scripts:

```
add_action( 'init', 'plugin_register_css_js' );
function plugin_register_css_js()
{
    global $wp;
    $current_url = add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) );

    if( $current_url == 'mypage' )
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'js', $jsdir . '/script1.js', array( 'jquery' ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @doktorgradus! Thanks for response. This what i get when I your suggested snippet [link]http://david.onenonly.info/
script1.js doesn't get included even if I put the absolute path

Comment: Hmm. In which directory `script1.js` are located? In plugin dir or in theme dir? Try `var_dump( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ));`, what it output?

Comment: script1.js is here: http://david.onenonly.info/wp-content/plugins/childtheme/js/script1.js 
As you can see i check option value before adding form to the page
    `if(dk_options.opt){
  contentID.appendChild(newForm);
 }`
and i pass 'dk_options.opt' to the script like this
    `wp_localize_script('dk_js_myplugin','dk_options',$opt);` in my php file

Comment: I understand that you define `jsdir` and use `wp_enqueue_script` not in function? You can use `define()` just after `<?php`, but `wp_enqueue_script` you must place into function - I edit my code by adding init func for `wp_enqueue_script`.

Comment: Thank you @doktorgradus. I have placed `wp_enqueue_script`inside a **plugin_register_css_js** function but i call that function like this: `add_action('template_redirect','is_home_check');` and inside `is_home_check` i check 
`if(is_home()){
    plugin_register_css_js();
}`
Isn't this a correct way to include the script on the page that needs it and not on all the pages?
P.S. Glad to write that **it worked** after I changed _template_redirect_ to _init_ Спасибо

Comment: About loading scripts on specified page you can read here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-load-specific-java-script-on-specific-page

Comment: Thanks doctor, you helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Some times its a permissions problem if you have access via FTP (I assume you do) then try playing around with the permissions. It might also help to turn php errors on.

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
ini_set('display_errors', 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try and post results

Comment: Sad to write but including `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` and `ini_set(...)` didn't reveal anything

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check via Firebug, that it loads the script1.js file (without generating a 404 error), on your remote server ?

Comment: Hello @Laurent, I checked the 'Script' tab of firebug on the page and it doesn't show the script. Do you mean this? See the page, please: http://david.onenonly.info/

Answer (score 0):

The script1.js file is not "called" by your browser (see picture attached)[image]

I'll suggest that you recheck your module, so you can make sure the script is loaded in the  tag.

Comment: Hello @Laurent the script address is this: http://david.onenonly.info/wp-content/plugins/childtheme/js/script1.js
but it doesn't get included even when I insert the absolute URL: `wp_enqueue_script('dk_js_myplugin','http://david.onenonly.info/wp-content/plugins/childtheme/js/script1.js',array('jquery'));`
Do you have any idea why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the following :

```
function load_dk_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'dk_js_myplugin',
        'http://david.onenonly.info/wp-content/plugi‌​ns/childtheme/js/script1.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_dk_scripts');
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in `add_action` function